# Number of Automorphism (based on Isomorphism)

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

$X, X'$  be two connected graphs  and let $Z$ be there  $Disjoint$  union.  $D=Aut(X) \times Aut(X')$ . How  does $|D|< |Aut(Z)|$  **if and only if** $X \simeq X'$ ? An example would be helpful.

In Non-Isomorphic case, should  $D$  be lesser  ?

**Context:-**

See the red-boxed line.

[image]

--From "Lecture Notes in Computer Science" by Christoph M. Hoffmann.

It is easy  to see that $D \leq Aut(Z)$. But, I could not comprehend the statement, " $D$ is a proper subgroup *iff* $X$ and $X'$ are isomorphic." Why ***$D$ is a proper subgroup*** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real key is that, since $X$ and $X^{\prime}$ are disjoint connected components of $Z$, any automorphism of $Z$ either stabilizes both $X$ and $X^{\prime}$ (in which case it is in $\mathrm{Aut}(X)\times \mathrm{Aut}(X^{\prime})$), or else it switches them (which can only happen when $X\simeq X^{\prime}$).

If $X\simeq X^{\prime}$ then there is some $\tau \in \mathrm{Aut}(Z)$ sending the vertices of $X$ to the vertices of $X^{\prime}$, that means $\tau \not\in D$ and so $D$ is a proper subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(Z)$. If $X\not\simeq X^{\prime}$ then there is no such $\tau$ and so $D=\mathrm{Aut}(Z)$ (i.e. $D$ is not a proper subgroup).